# numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching

Tags: python, path, scikit-image, image-preprocessing

I'm iterating through a directory to resize images and then save the newly reshaped images in another existing directory. I keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "preprocessingdatacopy.py", line 23, in <module>
    new_filename = image_resized + 'new.png'
numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U32'), dtype('<U32')) -> dtype('<U32')
```

The code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import skimage
from sklearn import preprocessing
from skimage import data, color
import os
from skimage.transform import resize, rescale
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from skimage import io
import cv2
import os
from pathlib import Path
directory_in_str = "/home/briannagopaul/imagemickey/"
directory = os.fsencode(directory_in_str)
for file in os.listdir(directory):
    print(file)
    filename = directory_in_str + os.fsdecode(file)
    if filename.endswith(".png"):
        img = mpimg.imread(filename)
        # cropped = img[484:384, 380:384]
        image_resized = resize(img, (128, 128))
        path2 = ("/home/briannagopaul/preprocessed")
        new_filename = image_resized + 'new.png'
        image_file.save(str(path2 / new_filename))
```

Comment: You're trying to add a string to a resized image. `mpimg` is not sure how to add those two object types together. Did you mean to add to the filename instead?

Comment: change `image_resized` to `path2 + file` `image_reized` is a numpy array not a string

Comment: Do you mean change the variable declaration of ```image_resized```? @Tyger

Comment: yes, exactly. I'm not sure how I would create a file name for the newly generated image though. It hasnt been saved yet. I'm thinking of using cv2's ```imread```. Any thoughts on this? @G.Anderson

Comment: I got the following error: @Tyger ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "preprocessingdatacopy.py", line 23, in <module>
    new_filename = path2 + "/" + file
TypeError: must be str, not bytes```

Comment: Seems as easy as swapping `new_filename = image_resized + 'new.png'` with `new_filename = filename + 'new.png'`, then `image_resized.save(...`

Comment: @G.Anderson I get: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "preprocessingdatacopy.py", line 24, in <module>
    image_resized.save(str(path2 / new_filename))
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'save'```
 because ```image_resize``` is a numpy array still.

Comment: When you read an image in, it's read as a numpy array. Then when you resize it, it's still an array. According to [the docs](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.io.html#skimage.io.imsave), the correct function for skimage to save a file is `skimage.io.imsave( filename, arr, *args)`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot concatenate an image to a string. You need to replace image_resized with a string data type (i.e the file name) because [skimage.transform.resize()](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.transform.html#resize) returns an image as an N-dimensional array.